# How to use mobile connect SMS in Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, sendsmsactivity

i have created a send able DE with mobile number and i am using same DE as a entry source in the Journey builder,

created Outbound SMS with personalization.

In Journey builder i have configured the SMS send activity.
activated the journey immediately, but not got any SMS.

i have checked in Event Result of the entry source, it is showing contact evaluated =5 Contact accepted =0

Attached screenshot.

Can you suggest, where i am doing wrong or procedure and rules to use mobile connect SMS in journey builder.

[image]

Comment: have you imported you mobile audience?

Comment: yes manually imported to the DE.

Comment: Just now again i have checked the Event Result of the entry source, it is showing contact evaluated =10 Contact accepted =6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this,
before sending SMS via Journey builder,

Step 1- mobile numbers should be present in mobile connect

Step 2- There is a Locale field in mobile connect which should be specified in the DE eg:- https://countrycode.org/

these two are main solutions to use Mobile connect SMS in Journey Builder. remaining regular configuration in Journey Builder.

Answer (score 2):

First check your DE attribtues.
The DE should contain 
Subscrirbey key with Text as datatype,
an email address with an email address as datatype and
a phone number field.

In the send relationship, subscriber key should be related to "All subscribers"

Next step, Configuring journey SMS activity.[image: subscriber opt-in choices]

If you have selected, ***Send only to contacts who are subscribed currently***, then you need to create a mobile contact list and loaded all your mobile numbers, locale and subscribed to a keyword
or
You can choose ***Subscribe all Contacts to a keyword***. 
This will subscribe contacts’ phone numbers in real-time to a keyword of your choice as they hit the activity.

The last step, Make sure you have chosen the correct phone field in the journey settings.

Note: Your phone number should also contain the country code.
Example: Singapore country code: 65
Mobile Number: 9898 9898
so Valid phone number is: 6598989898
[image]

Comment: i have done all this, but still not receiving the SMS,

Comment: Can you just test the outbound sms in Mobile connect? Is it working there?